# Ordering contents from a file by date stamps

Tags: vb.net, logging

I have so far made a script in Visual Basic with the program Visual Studio 2015 Community Edition.
What I'm struggling to find, is a solution for how I can order the content by a time stamp. Here's an example of how the file contents looks like:

```
dd.mm.yyyy hh.mm.ss text to end of line here
01.10.2015 06.50.43 Somebody tried to log into [username] with an incorrect password from [ip]
```

This is basically what all the log files contains. A date stamp and some information separated by a space.

So far, my script checks for file existence, then if the file exists, stores all the lines from the file into an "List (Of Strings)".

When it has found all the lines and reaches the end of stream, it prints out the "log" in a richtextbox in the same window. What I want to happen here before it prints out the contents, is that the script orders by the time stamps now stored in the list of strings from the oldest to newest, if possible.

Any suggestions?

Comment: My first suggestion for you is to use the right nomenclature: VB.NET is different than VBScript (and than Basic, a tag you are including too). VB.NET is not a scripting language and, consequently, you shouldn't use the word "script". My second recommendation is: share what you have tried, your code; don't need to talk about it (neither show a picture of it), just show the code. But bear in mind that SO is not a write-some-code-for-me service; your question has to be specific enough.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

An easy but ugly solution could be

```
lst_string.Sort(Function(x, y) DateTime.ParseExact(x.Substring(0, 19), "dd.MM.yyyy HH.mm.ss", System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture).CompareTo(DateTime.ParseExact(y.Substring(0, 19), "dd.MM.yyyy HH.mm.ss", System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture)))
```

but you maybe be better off creating a class for your inputdata separated by datetime and comment if you will like so

```
Dim ld As New LoginData
ld.dateLogedIn = DateTime.ParseExact(lst_string(0).Substring(0, 19), "dd.MM.yyyy HH.mm.ss", System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture)
ld.commentary = lst_string(0).Substring(20)
```

in that way it is easier to add more parameters for you like the username or ip and to sort by these accordingly

```
lst_newList.Sort(Function(x, y) x.dateLogedIn.CompareTo(y.dateLogedIn))
```